# Which is better to use three definitions of variables in React ES6? Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Consider these three ways of declaring an array `arr`:

```
// One
const arr = [7,8,9]; 
class WatchStore extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  ......
}

// Two
class WatchStore extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arr: [7,8,9],
    }
  }
  ......
}

// Three
class WatchStore extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.arr = [7,8,9]; 
  }
  ......
}
```

Which of these is the most "correct" and considered best practice? `arr` does not need to be rendered, it's just temporary cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semantically, the second differs from the other two. The reason is, as you stated:

> `arr` does not need to be rendered, it's just temporary cache.

Only ever put items in state if they are actively being changed and are important to the *state of the component*. Even if you don't ever mutate it after the initial render, this is a semantic issue. If it does not pertain to state, (as in it will never change in a way meaningful to the display of the component), it should not go in state.

As for the first and third, it involves a degree of opinion. A rule of thumb I like to use is to *restrict variables to their narrowest scope*. If something is declared in a higher scope, such as outside of class in the first example, but is not used outside the class, then don't declare it there. This is best practice because it eliminates unnecessary scope pollution, and even if it doesn't really apply here, it's a good habit to follow. Thus, choosing the third would be the most "correct" **if you set `this.arr` in the constructor, not a lifecycle hook** in the sense it semantically conveys the idea that `arr` pertains to component itself, but not state, and restricts `arr` to the narrowest scope possible.

As Joshua Rubin points out, don't use a lifecycle hook. There's no reason to so, since you'd be perfectly fine setting it directly in the constructor.

Comment: 'restrict variables to their narrowest scope' is a helpful suggestion.

Comment: First, thank you.As for the second,will it cause render or diff algorithms? This is the most confusing place I have right now.

Comment: @sosout Nothing will be rerendered unless you set state or force a rerender.

Answer (score 0):

If `arr` never changes, there's no need to store it as component state and there's no also need to hang it on the unnecessary lifecycle hook `componentDidMount`, that just complicates the component.  That leaves One - which is at least very clear.

You *could* also set `this.arr` in the constructor if `arr` isn't needed elsewhere.  And if, for the sake of discussion, you wanted to generate multiple instance of this a component with different definitions of `arr`, you might consider passing it into the constructor via props and setting `this.arr` there so that the value is component specific.